# Web-cam performance on Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: webcam

I want to film a small tutorial and for this reason I bought this[Webcam 1440P](https://www.amazon.de/dp/B08HV5KQ7Z/ref=cm_sw_r_u_apa_fabc_OSe6Fb7VTSQN8?_encoding=UTF8&psc=1), since I need more resolution than what my integrated laptop web-cam can offer. I have a Sony Vaio laptop with these specs:

[image]

Regardless if I use Cheese or OBS Studio, a 1280×720 resolution will render the camera or the app unresponsive.

My question now is: are my setup specs just to low for the resolution I intend to film with or am I missing something?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.
Thanks! Constantin

Comment: Hi Constantin! No, your laptop's specs shouldn't be an issue. I'm not clear how you're setting the webcam's resolution. Could you explain? What happens when you open Cheese and select your external webcam?

Comment: In Cheese for example: in video mode, go to the Menu (hamburger icon) and in preferences you can choose which cam to use and set up resolution and stuff. If I use the maximum allowed 1280x720 the app freezes. Strange is that I use my cam from the Android smartphone Cat S60 and connect it via droidcam and in this case Cheese doesn't give me the option to set the smartphone camera to a higher resolution  than 640x480.

Comment: Hi, it might be a problem with autofocus you could try installing v4l2-utils via apt and then v4l2-ctl -d /dev/video2 -c exposure_auto=2  (you should set videox where x is the video port used by your external webcam, the list of video ports is given by ls -ltrh /dev/video*). If that does not work, try fiddling with any parameter listed by v4l2-ctl -d /dev/video2 -l